# Is it possible to sell a portion of a house that someone still lives in (In Italy) to a third party?

Tags: real-estate, italy

I have a friend who owns (along with hr brother and mother) an equal share in a family property that was inherited from the father when he passed away last year.

It is a large property (six bedroom), with about an acre of land. My friend and her brother want to sell their portions (effectively 2/3rds of the house), but their mother is not too keen on selling.

Is it possible to legally sell their equity stake in the house, so that they can liquidate that holding and move on with their respective lives?

Specifically:

1. Is there a marketplace for such transactions?
2. How does one go about selling part of a house in which one has ownership in?

Comment: Who lives in that property? Your friend's mother? A tenant?

Comment: @SJuan76 Sorry, I should have made that clearer in my question. It is my friend's mother who lives in the house in question.